# Watermark on HTML Video with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add watermark on video element using CSS. But this Code is not working

```
  .v-wrap img{
            width: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: 200;
        }

    <div class="v-wrap">
      <img src="images/watemark.png" alt="logo">
         <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="320px" height="240px" controls 
             preload="none" poster='../images/digital-marketing.svg' data-setup='{"aspectRatio":"320:240", "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2] }'>
           <source src="../images/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
         </video>
     </div>
```

Comment: We can't help fix the CSS if there is no CSS to fix. Please add a [mcve] of the issue you're having

Comment: A [watermark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermark) is used to identify the ownership of, e.g., a video. How does adding a "logo"/overlay with CSS help with that?

Comment: Does `.v-wrap` have a `position` set to something other than `static`?

Answer (score 0):

Your watermark was placed at the bottom right, vs top left. Its now over the video. I added a white background so you can see it but you can remove it if you'd like.

```
video {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.v-wrap img {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    background: white;
}
```

Edit:
If you were trying to have the watermark at the bottom right of the video you could add position relative to the container (.v-wrap) and then change it to inline-block so that the edge of the container is the edge of the video. Like this

```
.v-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.v-wrap img {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: What’s the reason for the video styles?

Comment: It was mainly to have it flush with the edge of the watermark + put it behind the watermark.